# Most efficient way to implement this?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have been given a string:

```
00122334455667788990875645346787659870984780...
```

the above given string size will always be even.
i have to implement a method which will return an Arraylist of String where each element will contain 2 chars. for example for above string:

```
1st position of arraylist will contain: 00
2nd: 12
3rd: 23
...
```

I have tried to implement it myself, this is how my functions looks like:

```
private static ArrayList<String> getArrayListFrom(String data) {
    if(data.length()%2==0){
        ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
        char[] dArray = data.toCharArray();
        //logic here.
        for(int i = 0; i < dArray.length + 2; i = i+2){
            if(i != 0){
                aList.add(dArray[i-2]+""+dArray[i-1]);
            }
        }
        return aList;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796226/best-practices-for-regex-performance-vs-sheer-iteration) URL suggests that simple iteration is more efficient in this case. do you guys agree ?

Comment: What is your criteria for efficiency? Performance? Conciseness?

Comment: It should be able to process large string like this as soon as possible. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with a single split (Well, this may not be most efficient at runtime, but this is concise, lesser code to write):

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G..)");
```

And then get the `List<String>` using `Arrays#asList()` method.

The regex pattern splits on an empty space preceded by 2 characters - `..`, but ignoring the character already considered in previous match - `\\G`. The anchor `\\G` matches at the position where the previous match ended.

```
String str = "00122334455667788990875645346787659870984780";
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G..)");

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

prints:

```
[00, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 90, 87, 56, 45, 34, 67, 87, 65, 98, 70, 98, 47, 80]
```

---

Here's how split is done on your string:

```
   " 00     1    2       2334455667788990875645346787659870984780"  (whitespaces represent empty string) 
//     |       |       |
//   split,  no-split, split -> gives 12
//   |    |  |      |  
//   \    /  \      /
//  gives 00  as the preceding two characters are `1` and `0`.
//            but 0 is already considered for the previous empty string
```

---

**Reference:**

- [Continuing match using \G - Regular Expression info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)

---

If runtime performance is an issue, then you can go with simple looping:

```
String str = "00122334455667788990875645346787659870984780";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
    list.add(str.substring(i, i + 2));
} 
System.out.println(list);
```

But you can check for yourself, whether the regex split is really a performance bottleneck for large string, and benchmark both of them appropriately.

---

I benchmarked both the methods - split, and loop. And as expected loop is almost 4-5 times more efficient than split for a string of length say `1000`.

```
public static void usingSplit(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G..)");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
}

public static void usingLoop(String str) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
        list.add(str.substring(i, i + 2));
    }
}

// Warm up JVM
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        usingSplit(str);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
        usingLoop(str);
    }

    long nano = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        usingSplit(str);
    }
    System.out.println("Time with usingSplit(): " + (System.nanoTime() - nano) * 1.0 / Math.pow(10, 9) + " Seconds");

    nano = System.nanoTime();
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
        usingLoop(str);
    }
    System.out.println("Time with usingLoop(): " + (System.nanoTime() - nano) * 1.0 / Math.pow(10, 9) + " Seconds");
```

Output on few successive runs:

```
Run 1:
Time with usingSplit(): 34.391315143 Seconds
Time with usingLoop(): 7.515221612 Seconds

Run 2:
Time with usingSplit(): 33.41518869 Seconds
Time with usingLoop(): 7.868896218 Seconds
```

If someone thinks that the benchmark result is flawed, then please make a note of it in comments.

Comment: regular expressions are interpreted and so inefficient.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov. Well, sometimes a task is really meant to be done using regex. Iterating over the string is also an option. But you simply write less codes with split. And it is not that much inefficient as you are assuming.

Comment: @RohitJain (humbly) i have mentioned an url which suggests that in some cases simple iteration is more efficient. What do you think ?

Comment: @dreamer. Well, it depends if there are other more efficient solution. Regex, IMO might not be more efficient at runtime, than loop. Ultimately, it's you to decide what to use. Don't believe on what you hear. Benchmark the solutions yourself.

Comment: @dreamer: The question you should be asking yourself is, "Self, do you actually need efficiency to the point where using literally over twenty times as much code to do the same thing is worthwhile?"  If you don't, then using a regex is far more maintainable in this case.

Comment: @RohitJain for my problem simple iteration method did the job. again thanks for your effort. (^_^)

Comment: +1 for that, it is a shame that such a beautiful answer is not accepted.

Comment: @Sniffer i agree, but for my job iteration did the magic. Also i don't  get that there are always someone who are in a hurry to downvote my questions. i try to be as descriptive as possible. but sometimes it is difficult.

Comment: @Sniffer regex will probably be at least one order of magnitude slower than the accepted solution.

Comment: @assylias. I agree. When I benchmarked it, I found loop almost 4 times as efficient than regex. And that I have mentioned in answer too.

Comment: @assylias: Which matters if this is done a thousand times a second.  Not so much if it's, say, once an hour.

Comment: @dreamer I am not the one who down voted your question, that I promise. On the other hand, you are totally free to accept whichever solution you find best to solve your problem, I suggest happen to love this solution because I love regular expressions.

Comment: @assylias It is probably true, nevertheless I like this solution very much. The OP is of course to accept the solution that best fits his needs.

Comment: @Sniffer I believe you. Actually I don't care if someone downvote my question, The thing is that if this continues i wont be able to ask questions on SO in near future. (I am the one who upvoted your comment :-))

Comment: @dreamer I will fix that one for you :)

Comment: I don't see the reason for downvote on the answer. Can @Downvoter post appropriate comment?

Comment: In `usingLoop`, you need to put `list.ensureCapacity(str.length()/2);` to avoid the overhead of repeatedly resizing your list. It cuts the runtime by about 20% despite division. The for loop becomes `list.add(i/2,str.substring(i,i+2));`.  Changing it to use a shift or multiplication runs just as fast since `i/2` is computed using a shift itself.

Answer (score 5):

```
    ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //logic here.
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i+=2){
        aList.add(data.subString(i, i+2));
    }
    return aList;
```

Comment: For better performance, especially if the string is very long, size the list beforehand: `new ArrayList<>(data.length/2);`

Comment: Probably using `Vector` since OP says he/she is using J2ME.

Comment: @bsd I will first try implementing it using Vector.